# Text overlay in a table

Tags: tables, nicematrix

I am creating some cockburn tables using this [wonderful site](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) suggested to me. The problem I encountered is that the table below looks like this:

[image]

What do I expect

[image]

As you can see, the table is very narrow and has overlaid text. I have no idea how to fix it.

Attached I leave you the code that the site itself has generated. **As always thanks for your time.**

```
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}

    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
        \textbf{Use Case #2} &
          \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Effettua registrazione con email} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Goal in context} &
          \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente vuole effettuare la registrazione alla piattaforma con la propria email} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Precondition} &
          \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente non è autenticato} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Success End Condition} &
          \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente riesce a registrarsi alla piattaforma} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Failed End Condition} &
          \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente non si registra alla piattaforma} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Primary Actor} &
          \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Ospite} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Trigger} &
          \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente preme il pulsante "profilo" della bottombar dell'APP_HOME} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
          \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Step} &
          \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Ospite} &
          \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Sistema} \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
          1 &
          \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}L'utente preme il pulsante "profile"\\ della bottombar della APP_HOME\end{tabular} &
           \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
          2 &
           &
          \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Il sistema mostra dialogIscriptionRequest \\ che avvisa l'utente che per usufruire di tutte le funzionalità presenti\\  deve essere iscritto\end{tabular} \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
          3 &
          \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}L'utente preme il pulsante "iscriviti"\\  della dialogIscriptionRequest\end{tabular} &
           \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
          4 &
           &
          Mostra la schermata di autenticazione APPM_AUTHENTICATION \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
          5 &
          Preme il pulsante "Accedi con email" &
           \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
          6 &
           &
          Mostra la schermata per l'accesso \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
          7 &
          Preme il pulsante "Registrati" &
           \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
          8 &
           &
          Mostra la schermata per la registrazione APPM_SIGNUP \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
          9 &
          Compila i campi necessari &
           \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
          10 &
          Preme il pulsante "Iscriviti" &
           \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-12}{*}{\textbf{Description}}} &
          11 &
           &
          Mostra schermata home APPM_HOME \\ \hline
         &
          \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Step} &
          \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Ospite} &
          \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Sistema} \\ \cline{2-4} 
         &
          3.1 &
          Preme il pulsante "Più tardi" &
           \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multirow{-3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}EXTENSION #1\\ L'utente preme il pulsante \\ "Più tardi" annullando \\ l'operazione\end{tabular}} &
          4.1 &
           &
          Torna alla schermata iniziale APP_HOME e termina il caso d'uso \\ \hline
         &
          \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Step} &
          \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Ospite} &
          \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Sistema} \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}EXTENSION #2\\ L'utente inserisce un'email\\ già presente nel sistema\end{tabular}} &
          11.2 &
           &
          Mosra un Toast di errore \\ \hline
         &
          \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Step} &
          \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Ospite} &
          \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Sistema} \\ \cline{2-4} 
         &
          9.3 &
          \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Preme il pulsante \\ "Back" \\ dell'APPM_SIGNUP\end{tabular} &
           \\ \cline{2-4} 
         &
          10.3 &
           &
          Torna alla schermata APPM_AUTHENTICATION \\ \cline{2-4} 
         &
          11.3 &
          Preme il pulsante "Accedi come ospite" &
           \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multirow{-5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}EXTENSION #3\\ L'utente decide\\ di non voler effettuare \\ l'autenticazione\end{tabular}} &
          12.3 &
           &
          Torna alla schermata APPM_HOME e termina il caso d'uso \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
        }
        \caption{Effettua registrazione con email}
        \label{tab:tck_registrazione_email}
        \end{table}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: Since you used resizebox : please keep on mind that using the command in a table will result in  inconsistent and often illegibly small font sizes.

Comment: Also, replace `#` with `\#` and text like `APP_HOME` with `APP\_HOME` or `APP\textsubscript{HOME}` depending on the expected output (litaral _ character or subscript "HOME".)

Comment: @leandriis I added the result I expect, thanks for your time

Comment: The `l`,`r` and `c` column cannot break the line of a cell, so the width of the column is a bit more that the width of the longest text. Use of `p{<lenght>}` columns (e.g. `p{5cm}`) or search about the `tabular*` environment  and the `tabulary` and `tabularx` packages. You might also want to take a look at the `booktabs` package, although not for fix the width of the columns.

Answer (score 2):

- your table is huge
- page layout is unknow
- in following suggestion is assumed:

  - that font size in table can be smaller, i.e. be of `\footnotesize
  - line spread can be reduced
  - page layout is defined by `geometry` package default settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage{multirow, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize%
                       \centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize%
                       \raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
                       }X}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{L}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|O{L{1}}|C{0.3}|O{L{1}}|O{L{1.7}}|}
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}
\textbf{Use Case \#2} &
  \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Effettua registrazione con email} \\ \hline
\textbf{Goal in context} &
  \multicolumn{3}{L{3.2}|}{L'utente vuole effettuare la registrazione alla piattaforma con la propria email} \\ \hline
\textbf{Precondition} &
  \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente non è autenticato} \\ \hline
\textbf{Success End Condition} &
  \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente riesce a registrarsi alla piattaforma} \\ \hline
\textbf{Failed End Condition} &
  \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente non si registra alla piattaforma} \\ \hline
\textbf{Primary Actor} &
  \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Ospite} \\ \hline
\textbf{Trigger} &
  \multicolumn{3}{L{3.2}|}{L'utente preme il pulsante "profilo" della bottombar dell'APP\_HOME}
                \\  \hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}
\cellcolor{white}
    & \textbf{Step} 
        & \textbf{Ospite} & \textbf{Sistema} \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 1 & L'utente preme il pulsante "profile" della bottombar della APP\_HOME
            &   \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 2 &   & Il sistema mostra dialogIscriptionRequest che avvisa l'utente che per usufruire di tutte le funzionalità presenti deve essere iscritto   \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 3 & L'utente preme il pulsante "iscriviti"  della dialogIscriptionRequest
            &   \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 4 &   & Mostra la schermata di autenticazione APPM\_AUTHENTICATION \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 5 & Preme il pulsante "Accedi con email" 
            &   \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 6 &   & Mostra la schermata per l'accesso \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 7 & Preme il pulsante "Registrati" 
            &   \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 8 &   & Mostra la schermata per la registrazione APPM\_SIGNUP \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 9 & Compila i campi necessari 
            &   \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 10& Preme il pulsante "Iscriviti" 
            &   \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-34}{=}{\textbf{Description}} 
    &11 &   & Mostra schermata home APPM\_HOME 
                \\  \hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}
\cellcolor{white}
    & \textbf{Step}
        & \textbf{Ospite} 
            & \textbf{Sistema} 
                \\ \cline{2-4}
    &3.1& Preme il pulsante "Più tardi" 
            &   \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-5}{=}{EXTENSION \#1:\newline
                 L'utente preme il pulsante "Più tardi" annullando l'operazione} 
    &4.1&   &   Torna alla schermata iniziale APP\_HOME e termina il caso d'uso
                \\ \hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}
\cellcolor{white}
    & \textbf{Step}
        & \textbf{Ospite}
            & \textbf{Sistema}
                \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 11.2  &   & Mosra un Toast di errore 
                \\ 
\multirow{-4}{=}{EXTENSION \#2\newline
                 L'utente inserisce un'email già presente nel sistema}
    &       &   &   \\ \hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}
\cellcolor{white}
    & \textbf{Step}
            & \textbf{Ospite}
                & \textbf{Sistema}
                    \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 9.3   & Preme il pulsante "Back" dell'APPM\_SIGNUP
                &   \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 10.3  &   & Torna alla schermata APPM\_AUTHENTICATION 
                    \\ \cline{2-4}
    & 11.3  & Preme il pulsante "Accedi come ospite" 
                &   \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-5}{=}{EXTENSION \#3\newline 
                 L'utente decide di non voler effettuare l'autenticazione} 
    & 12.3  &   & Torna alla schermata APPM\_HOME e termina il caso d'uso 
                    \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Effettua registrazione con email}
\label{tab:tck_registrazione_email}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note: your table code fragment doesn't reproduce showed table, but this mismatch you can correct yourself.

If you compare both table codes, you can observe:

- For table is used `tabularx` table environment
- From `X` column type are derived are two new column type: `C` and `L`. They enable simple settings of their width ratios.
- To cells are added vertical space by help of `cellspace` package.
- Thee way of table coloring is changed. `\cellcolor` is used only in the first column, others are replaced by `rowcolor. This make code a not so small bit shorter.
- For `multirow` cells is used its new syntax `\multirow{-...}{=}{...}` (observe `=`). By this nested tables in those cells become superfluous.

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Answer (score 0):

The table presented looks like part of a project documentation, perhaps a GUI. That means it will be a living document,
with changes and additions throughout the life of the project.
So it will be a futile exercise trying to fit this particular table on a single page. It won't last the first draft.

Looking closely, it seems to me that there are three parts to the table, each of which conveys a different type of information.

(1) The upper part, with a general description of the case, its objectives, success criteria, etc. It probably won't change much over time.

(2) The intermediate part that follows the actions of the user and the response of the subsystems. It will be different for each case.

(3) The lower part, with the reactions of the subsystems in the case of odd terminations.
Different for other cases and probably undergoing numerous additions over time from later findings on testing and operational use.

That is why I propose to divide the original table into three tables, each dedicated to its specific task.

[image: a2]

[image: b2]

[image: C]

In this way it will be easy to add new lines or modify the content without accidentally altering the other parts.

I chose to use the `nicematrix`  package because by itself provides all the facilities needed for this task.

For starters it provides the command `\Block` that replaces the `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` and allow the use of `\\` inside.

It also allows general directives like `hvlines`. That takes care of the `\hlines` and `\cline {2-4}` within the code.

Overall the code is much cleaner and easier to maintain when revisited some time in the future.

Notes:

(1) All cells are vertically centered. Notice, for example, the numbers in the Steps column. This happens automatically, even in multiple rows cells.

(2) Using `\\` inside the `\Block` you can cut the sentence following the pauses of the natural way of speaking, facilitating reading.

(3) No change of the font size is needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % everything needed

\usepackage{float} % provides[H]    
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}
    
\section{Utente effettua registrazione con terze parti}

1. \kant[1] 

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Conditions of Use Case \#1}
\medskip
\begin{NiceTabular}{ll}[hvlines,
                        code-before = \rectanglecolor{gray!15}{1-1}{1-2},
                        cell-space-top-limit = 7pt,
                        cell-space-bottom-limit = 7pt]  
    \textbf{Use Case \#1}   & \textbf{Effettua registrazione con terze parti}                                                   \\  
    Goal in context         & \Block[l]{1-1}{L'utente vuole effettuare la registrazione alla piattaforma \\con la propria email}\\      
    Precondition            & L'utente non è autenticato                                                                        \\  
    Success End Condition   & L'utente riesce a registrarsi alla piattaforma                                                    \\
    Failed End Condition    & L'utente non si registra alla formatting                                                          \\
    Primary Actor           & Ospite                                                                                            \\  
    Trigger                 & \Block[l]{1-1}{L'utente preme il pulsante "profilo"  della bottom bar\\ dell' APP\_HOME}          \\
\end{NiceTabular}%      
\end{table}

9. \kant[9]

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Use Case \#1: user actions and responses step by step}
\medskip
\begin{NiceTabular}{c wc{4ex}  wc{4ex} wc{3ex}  wl{11.5cm}}[hvlines,
                                                            first-row,
                                                            code-for-first-row = \bfseries,
                                                            cell-space-top-limit = 7pt,
                                                            cell-space-bottom-limit = 7pt]          
Step    & \rotate{Ospite} & \rotate{API} & \rotate{Sistema} & \Block[c]{}{Description}\\
1       & X &   &   & \Block[l]{}{L'utente preme il pulsante "profile" della \\bottom bar della APP\_HOME}      \\
2       &   &   & X & \Block[l]{}{Il sistema mostra dialog Iscription Request  che avvisa l'utente \\ che per usufruire di tutte le funzionalità presenti \\  deve  essere iscritto} \\
3       & X &   &   & \Block[l]{}{L'utente preme il pulsante "iscriviti"  \\ della dialog Iscription Request}   \\
4       &   &   & X & \Block[l]{}{Mostra la schermata di autenticazione\\ APPM\_AUTHENTICATION}\\
5       & X &   &   & Preme il pulsante "Accedi con email"                                                      \\
6       &   & X &   &  Mostra la schermata per l'accesso                                                        \\
7       &   &   & X & Preme il  pulsante "Registrati"                                                           \\
\end{NiceTabular}%
\end{table}

12. \kant[12]

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Extensions of Use Case \#1}
\medskip
\begin{NiceTabular}{wl{5.5cm} c wc{4ex}  wc{4ex} wc{3ex}  wl{5.5cm}}[hvlines,
                                                                    first-row,
                                                                    code-for-first-row = \bfseries,
                                                                    cell-space-top-limit = 6pt,
                                                                    cell-space-bottom-limit = 6pt]  
\Block[c]{}{Extension}              & Step & \rotate{Ospite} & \rotate{API} & \rotate{Sistema} & \Block[c]{}{Description}\\ 
\Block{2-1}{EXTENSION  \#1 \\ L'utente preme  il pulsante \\ "Più tardi" annullando \\ l'operazione.}
                                    & 3.1  & X &   &   & \Block[l]{}{Preme il pulsante "Più tardi".}  \\
                                    & 4.1  &   &   & X & \Block[l]{}{Torna alla schermata iniziale \\APP\_HOME e  termina \\il caso d'uso.}\\
\Block{1-1}{EXTENSION \#2\\ L'utente inserisce un email\\ già presente nel sistema.}            
                                    & 5.2  &   &   & X & \Block[l]{}{Preme il pulsante "back".}  \\          
\Block{2-1}{EXTENSION \#3\\ L'utente decide di non voler \\effettuare l'autenticazione.}
                                    & 3.5  & X &   &   & \Block[l]{}{Torna alla schermata \\ APPM\_AUTHENTICATION}  \\  
                                    & 3.6  &   &   & X & \Block[l]{}{Torna alla schermata iniziale \\APP\_HOME e  termina \\il caso d'uso.}\\            
\end{NiceTabular}%        
\end{table}     
    
\end{document}
```